# Applications to run JavaScript

Tags: javascript, console

Alright, so I've learned most of what I know by learning at Codecademy. At the website as you code you get a console to see what happens as you code. Currently I'm trying to make a choose your own text adventure game on Aptana Studio. I'm trying to figure out how to have a console run the code to test out my current code. If there is a way to use Aptana or a program I can download that would be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1. First, [link the script to an HTML page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) and press [F12 to view the
   console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).
2. You can use Wscript.exe in the cmd passing in your js file. (This did not work for me however it has worked for others
3. Some may disagree, but you can run your script using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). In cmd after installing, type: `node <filename>.js`. [List to other Shells to run JS here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Shells).

Good luck!